# System path error with PyQt and Py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, exe, pyside, py2exe

## My Problem:

I have this problem where if I try to run py2exe on my python file that uses Pyqt/Pyside I get the following error when trying to run the EXE generated in I:\Documents\Python\Buttonio_Testio\dist :

### Error recieved when running Package.exe:

```
I:\Documents\Python\Buttonio_Testio\dist>Package.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Package.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 55, in <module>
  File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 87, in get_pyside_dir
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 83, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
  File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 58, in _get_win32_short_name
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

### My setup.py looks like this:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    setup(console=['Package.py'])

My program, in Package.py looks like this:

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

import Gui


class Ui_Dialog(QDialog, Gui.Ui_Dialog):
    #Setupui and function afterwards generated converting XML file made by QT Desiner to python.
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(279, 295)
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 192))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 251, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("PushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.textBrowser.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Clear Spam", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spam()

    def spam(self):
        self.textBrowser.append("SPAM")
        self.textBrowser.append("SPAM")
        self.textBrowser.append("SPAM")
        self.textBrowser.append("LOL")
        self.textBrowser.append("I")
        self.textBrowser.append("AM")
        self.textBrowser.append("SPAMMING")
        self.textBrowser.append("MYSELF")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Ui_Dialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am running windows 8 with 32bit python and 32bit modules installed. The setup.py file was in the same folder as Package.py when I ran setup.py in Command Prompt. Besides that I don't know what other information may help fix my problem.

That's all, thank you for any answers in advance.

Comment: I now have the same problem yet nobody can give a hint...

Comment: Did you find a solution by the way?

Comment: @foresightyj I get a different error, but originating from the same location, using Python 3.3.2 and PySide 1.2.0. I've posted a [question](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29881/) on the Qt forums, hopefully one of us will get an answer.

Comment: @Praetorian I am using Python 2.7.5. I also tried to sign in and post a question at pyqt's forum but I was able to find a POST where I could start a new post... My fix seems to be working fine so far. Hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that _utils.py used `__file__`, but `__file__` is not available in frozen executables. This has been fixed in PySide 1.2.1 that was released a few days ago (it was fixed by commit [817a5c9bd39d3a22e2a7db9aa497059be57d58d7](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside/commit/817a5c9bd39d3a22e2a7db9aa497059be57d58d7)).

Comment: Installing PySide v1.2.1 (from 1.2.0) did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Yep. The same error encountered again today with Pyside V1.2.1

Answer (score 7):

I was desperately looking for a solution to this for the past three hours. I ended up going into the _ _ init_ _.py file in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide directory. I changed the last line to the following:

```
try:
    _setupQtDirectories()
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

It is ugly I admit. I hope PySide people will fix this soon.

Comment: I fixed it in a slightly different manner, call the function only if the application is not frozen. `if not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'): _setupQtDirectories()`

Comment: Before we go willy nilly skipping this function - what is the point of it?

Comment: I would like to add that I have modified the function as Praetorian suggested and it appears to have solved my problems... but I'd still really like to hear what the point of the function is. Perhaps this should go in a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I never had time to figure it out. But in two months of using it, I never had any problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

for PySide 1.2.1: 
fix `get_pyside_dir()` function in PySide/_utils.py:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    ...
    def get_pyside_dir():
        is_frozen = hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
        try:
            from . import QtCore
        except ImportError: 
            s1 = sys.argv[0] if is_frozen else __file__
            return _get_win32_case_sensitive_name(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(s1)))
        else:
            s2 = sys.argv[0] if is_frozen else QtCore.__file__
            return _get_win32_case_sensitive_name(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(s2)))
else:
    def get_pyside_dir():
        is_frozen = hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
        try:
            from . import QtCore
        except ImportError:
            s1 = sys.argv[0] if is_frozen else __file__
            return os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(s1))
        else:
            s2 = sys.argv[0] if is_frozen else QtCore.__file__
            return os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(s2))
```

When using py2exe or other "freezer", the `__file__` value in `_utils.py` will point to file inside zip archive, which is obviosly not expected by PySide. So you have to handle this case and force `_utils.py` to use a path, where PySide dlls & stuff are really living (in my case - a directory, where .exe file is placed).

Comment: This works for me, thanks. I see a second definition of get_pyside_dir in _utils.py regarding the 64bit environment. Should this be modified as well or is the problem only 32bit related? I have Python 2.7 32bit installed and so cannot test it right now.

Comment: Yes, all occurences of get_pyside_dir must be fixed. I edited my answer to handle both cases: win32 and others - you may use it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing PySide 1.2.1 and still got this problem.

I just changed the `get_pyside_dir()` functions in `PySide._utils` to return my pyside path, which for me is "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide"